# Stax parser fails to read files with encoding UTF-16

Tags: java, stax

I am using stax parser to read an xml file inside a common api in my app. The api takes inputstream as parameter and i am doing something like below

```
public Object <commonApi>(InputStream is)
  XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
  XMLEventReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(is);
  try{     
      while (parser.hasNext()) {
      XMLEvent event = parser.nextEvent();
      // reaming parsing logic
     }
   } Catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

The issue is this works if the encoding in the xml file is UTF-8. If it is UTF-16, then it doesn't read properly..gives the following exception

> javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,41]
>   Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.

I can't change the signature of the common api. I need to operate on the inputstream.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`createXMLEventReader(InputStream stream, String encoding)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#createXMLEventReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) with `UTF-16` as `encoding`.

Comment: My code has to work for UTF-8 and UTF-16 or any other valid encoding. So, i need a generic way that works